# One code on dev server, and production server - how to deal with links?

Tags: php, path

I have a copy of a code running on the production server, and I use my local machine(s) running xampp as a dev server. I have several websites that I actively develop, so I'm forced to use http://localhost/sitename

All my URLs are relative to the domain, (/file.php). They work fine on the prod server, but on a local server, they all point to localhost, when I want to make them all work relative to the site folder they are in. Is there anything I could do, other than what I do now, which is this:

```
if($_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] == "localhost") {
 $path_to = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'] . "/folder";
 $path_to_files = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . "/folder";
} else {
 $path_to = "http://" . $_SERVER['SERVER_NAME'];
 $path_to_files = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'];
}
```

and simply putting `$path_to` before each link on the site.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a vhost instead.

So, in your hosts file, add something like:

`sitename.dev 127.0.0.1`

Then in `xampp/apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf`:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
        DocumentRoot "/xampp/htdocs/sitename"
        ServerName sitename.dev
</VirtualHost>
```

Restart Apache then browse to http://sitename.dev

This should provide the same behavior as production.

Read more about vhosts [here](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

Answer (score 2):

just dont work with host names in link image/file links.

http goes by root domain/folder/file.jpg => /folder/file.jpg - it doesnt need a http://domain

and script side you can refer to ./ or get your current path with **FILE** or similar functions/constants:

look into:

```
basename(dirname(__FILE__));
```

Answer (score 2):

Why not just use relative links:

```
<a href='/some/relative/path'>
```

Then to map filenames to URLs and back, use the relevant $_SERVER vars? (NB for simplicity you don't want too many directory trees associated with each website.

Alternatively just use $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] anywhere you need to supply the hostname?

C.

Comment: His main problem with relative links is that `/foo` will route to `localhost/foo` instead of `localhost/sitename/foo`.

Comment: The make them relative to some abstract datum (or the current file) rather than the webroot - e.g. '../foo'

Comment: that's not really a valid solution. Dynamic content cannot always know how "deep" it is - think about sites that use URL rewriting. But with a proper setup (e.g. through a vhost), one can always be sure where root truly is, and base link relation on that.

Answer (score 1):

The solution you give is a good one, but if you want to hard code absolute URLs, you can configure your dev apache with one virtual host for each site.

See the [Apache Virtual Host documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/).

You can either make Apache listen on several ports and assign a port for each site.

- http://localhost:81/ for site A
- http://localhost:82/ for site B
- ...

You can either make Apache listen on all IPs and use a different IP for each site.

- http://127.0.0.1/ for site A
- http://127.0.0.2/ for site B
- ...

Or you can edit create several hostnames that resolve to `127.0.0.1` and configure name based virtual hosting. You can either use a real DNS server or edit your hosts file, as suggested by Matt.

Answer (score 1):

What you wanna do is use virtual hosts in Apache. Use this in your httpd.conf:

```
NameVirtualHost 127.0.0.1

<VirtualHost localhost>
DocumentRoot "C:/My Documents/My Webs"
ServerName localhost
</VirtualHost>

<VirtualHost sitename>
DocumentRoot "C:/My Documents/My Webs/Site Name"
ServerName sitename
</VirtualHost>
```

Then in your hosts file (`C:\Windows\System32\Drivers\etc\hosts` on Windows) add the server name:

```
127.0.0.1        localhost sitename
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use virtual domains within your xampp development for your different clients?